# Using Python module on LGPL license in commercial product

Tags: python, licensing

There is written in LGPL license that I can use not modified, linked code in commercial, closed product without changing license of product to LGPL. What about Python module (*.py) on LGPL license in commercial product? Is it treated as linked code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think the issue (whether importing a Python module counts as "linking" with it, for the legal purposes of the GPL) has been settled yet. I don't think it will be resolved until a court case turns on it (and possibly not even then). The GPL is (sadly) written basically in terms of C and its associated tools, so it's only obvious how to apply it if the language and tools used for software have similar properties to those associated with C.

However, importing a Python module is surely at *least* as permissive a situation as dynamically linking to a shared library; which copyrighted document (source file) you link with when you type `import foo` isn't determined until the program is actually run, and can be trivially changed *after* your copyrighted document is produced by the end user moving .py files around on their system, or even just changing PYTHONPATH.

Personally, I find the above arguments lead clearly to the conclusion that adding `import foo` to your own source file doesn't "copy from or adapt all or part of [foo.py] in a fashion requiring copyright permission" **at all**, and thus the GPL doesn't really apply if you never modify foo.py. (Quote from [the GNU GPL version 3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html), under "0. Definitions")

(Technically I think this argument would apply to dynamically linking to a shared C library as well, except that to do so you've normally had to `#include <foo.h>`, which means your compiled program is a work based on foo.h even if you do argue that it's not a work based on the shared library. Although your *source* code would be completely unencumbered by the GPL with this interpretation, interestingly enough, so if you wanted to push the point you could distribute your source code with a proprietary license and instructions for the end user to compile themselves. But I digress.)

Not that common sense arguments necessarily match up with what a court would decide. If you treat `import foo.py` as "dynamically linking" with foo.py for the purposes of the (L)GPL, I do not see how you could go wrong - no one will sue you for adhering to license conditions you technically didn't have to.

Comment: Although logical unless you love lawsuits why chance it. The common understanding is avoid shipping any LGPL code in a commercial product unless it can be *compiled* into a shared library binary. Unfortunately Python cannot compile a module into a shared library binary. End-of-story.

Comment: As author of libraries, does it help if I additionally specify the definition of "linking" in the context of Python?

Comment: @Franklin Doing so is changing the license. So it wouldn't help you use an existing (L)GPL python library. If you want to put out python libraries using your variant of the (L)GPL then possibly, although you run the risk that your license is not necessarily considered compatible with the GPL.

Comment: Well all C programs normally do dynamic linking at runtime. Static linking is very rare, however GPL license applies for dynamic linking as well. But nice try.

Comment: @LtWorf I don't quite understand the relevance of your comment, since the main point of my answer ("treating Python imports as dynamic linking seems like it should be at least as restricted as you need to be") was entirely based on the idea that GPL licenses apply to dynamic linking.

Comment: @LtWorf Personally I don't think the GPL as written *does* apply to original code that dynamically links with a GPLed library. I know the FSF would like it to, but I don't think they've written that intent into the license, since it clearly states that a "covered work" is one that "copies from or adapts all or part of the work in a fashion requiring copyright permission" which dynamically linking doesn't (though #include does so it's a bit moot in C, but not Python). I'm not a copyright lawyer, so I'm not going to advise anyone tests that interpretation, but that seems to be what the words say

Comment: What you personally think is of no relevance. When you give answers please stick to facts.

Comment: @LtWorf Funny, I thought that by citing the actual text of the license that says which works it applies to I *was* sticking to facts. There's a lot of folklore about the GPL, often with little reference to the text itself. But your disagreement about the facts is noted.

Comment: @Ben please read https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLStaticVsDynamic

Comment: @LtWorf As I said, I'm aware that's what they would like the conditions to be. That's not what the license text actually says. And I don't think it's possible for it to work that way; if the relevant jurisdiction's copyright law doesn't say that my work is a derivative work of `gpled_module.py`merely because I wrote the name of it in an import statement, then I don't need any license to distribute my work on its own. And copyright laws that I'm aware of don't say that, any more than they say this comment infringes JK Rowling's copyright for referencing Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone.

Comment: @LtWorf Again, it mostly *does* work the way they want it to for compiled languages, since the compiled binary of your work that links againat the GPLed work *is* a derivative work (it's produced dom header material, contains inlined code, etc). Anyway, this is getting repetitive. Clearly I have not convinced you, and that is fine.

Comment: @Ben if you are confident that you can bribe the judge, sure. Otherwise, laws work by interpreting the intent of the thing, and you writing "import blabla" in an executable, is creating something that can't work without the module. So keep dreaming that the GPL only applies to statically linked binaries (no binary ever, since decades).

Comment: @LtWorf Okay, one thing I think you might be missing. I'm not talking about a distinction between static and dynamic linking per se, you're the one who brought that up. What I'm talking about is when one work counts as a derivative work of another; that's a question for the relevant copyright law, a license cannot redefine that (and anyway the GPL **explicitly** says that it only covers works that would require copyright permission even if the GPL wasn't involved; linking of any kind is not actually mentioned as a condition at all).

Comment: @Ben "I find the above arguments lead clearly to the conclusion that adding import foo to your own source file doesn't 'copy from or adapt all or part of [foo.py] in a fashion requiring copyright permission' at all" -- I believe this is true if this is all you do, but practically speaking, you probably would make some API calls. In that case, depending on the amount of API calls you have made, you may be systematically "copying" function names and their arrangements, which might "require copyright permission". Would that make sense?

Comment: Here are some other points of view: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Linking_and_derived_works . Overall, whether and how a dynamic linking program constitute derivative work seems largely unsettled. (Could you update the first sentence so that the statement can be more accurate?)

Comment: @xuhdev Leaving out the parenthetical, the first sentence is literally "I don't think the issue (...) has been settled yet". What would you like to be more accurate?

Comment: @xuhdev I don't believe any amount of code *using* an API is a derivative work under copyright laws that I am aware of (though I am not a lawyer). Copyright doesn't protect APIs, nor algorithms, nor names. It protects *documents*. The fact that some novel code you write uses a bunch of names defined in another work doesn't make your code a derivative of it, any more than a movie review is a derivative of the movie merely because it repeatedly uses names defined in the movie. A court may decide differently, but this is my analysis. Which is why I started that paragraph "Personally, I find...".

Comment: @Ben The content between the parentheses doesn't seem accurate to me. The core unsettled question seems to me "whether and how a dynamic linking program constitute derivative work". Additionally, I failed to see "The GPL is (sadly) written basically in terms of C and its associated tools", even for GPLv2.

Comment: Simply speaking, infringing copyright requires 3 elements when no permission is given (this condition aligns with GPLv3's definition of "modify"): (1) copyrightable elements, (2) the fact of copying these copyrightable elements, and (3) the copy does not fall into the ambit of fair use. What you are saying is that (1) doesn't establish when calling a library function, which I also believe is the key to the answer.

Comment: In this sense, your movie review example is misleading and somewhat irrelevant. A movie review isn't a derivative work simply because it straightly doesn't satisfy (3), regardless of (1) or (2). Had there been no fair use doctrine, it would yield a fact intensive inquiry on what is copied and whether the copied elements are copyrightable. If all the movie review does is to repeat names, it's hardly infringing. But in practice, it may retell part of the plots, which may be copyrightable.

Comment: Regarding (1) (which is often interwoven with (2)), copyright protects "expression", not "ideas". There's no bright line between expression and idea, and expressions aren't limited to "documents". One popularly employed test is [Abstraction-Filtration-Comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction-Filtration-Comparison_test). You can think of this test as slaying a computer program layer by layer, and identify the boundary of expression and idea. From this test, I don't think there's a per se rule on the effect of calling API. But as I commented above, there are different views.

Comment: @xuhdev So in your understanding it **HAS** been settled whether importing a python module counts as "linking" with it for the GPL?? Surely not? It sounds like I was just making a different point than you wanted me to be making in that sentence, rather than it was inaccurate. **MY** point was that **even if** we assume that dynamic linking does automatically create a derivative work, it **still** isn't clear whether a python import is dynamic linking. It's a separate unsettled question, and I chose this one because it speaks to the OP's question more specifically.

Comment: @xuhdev You're right, "expression" is a better term for the concept than "document". But I do not believe that referencing a part of somebody else's expression constitutes **copying** that expression. I'm saying that *I* do not believe (2) is established when calling a library function, rather than (1). (Well, I'm saying that the library **function** isn't being copied, which is (2), and that the library function's **name** isn't copyrightable, which is (1))

Comment: @xuhdev Again you're right, movie review isn't the best analogy. A better one might be a recipe book; if I write a recipe for a cake which includes "Make the icing from Xuhdev's Delicious Treats, page 47" as a step, is my recipe's expression a derivative work of yours? The algorithm it describes depends on yours in a functional sense, but surely the *expression* of mine does not constitute a *copy* of yours, simply by referring to it? But I am aware that that is my reasoning, not a court's, and is controversial, so I did not make it the crux of my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Simple test - can the user swap the LGPL part for their own version?

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if you can use a LGPL’ed library within a closed source commercial product.  While I couldn’t find anything that addressed this specific situation, everything suggests there should be no issues. First, there is an article on use of [LGPL in Java](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-java.html%5D).  This is the relevant quote from the article:

> FSF's position has remained constant throughout: the LGPL works as intended with all known  programming languages, including Java. Applications which link to LGPL libraries need not be released under the LGPL. Applications need only follow the requirements in section 6 of the LGPL: allow new versions of the library to be linked with the application; and allow reverse engineering to debug this.

One other additional quote from the article that may be relevant:

> When you distribute the library with your application (or on its own), you need to include source code for the library. But if your application instead requires users to obtain the library on their own, you don't need to provide source code for the library.

And one last quote:

> The LGPL contains no special provisions for inheritance, because none are needed. Inheritance creates derivative works in the same way as traditional linking, and the LGPL permits this type of derivative work in the same way as it permits ordinary function calls.

While it is true that this particular case has not been tried in a court of law (at least that I know of), I wouldn’t stay up at night worrying about it.  Even if the LGPL isn’t exactly clear on this issue, the FSF has published guidance that the LGPL works as expected for all programming languages.   In general, if a contract is ambiguous, then it is resolved in favor of the defendant (this is an oversimplification, but you can find more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra_proferentem)).  If you are really nervous, I would consider contacting the [Free Software Foundation](http://www.fsf.org/licensing/contact).

In summary, it looks like you can use LGPL software with Python if you either distribute the LGPL'ed library's source code with your application (along with your modifications) or you make the end user install this library separately.

Answer (score 1):

A python library imported by your program is certainly not statically linked, the compiled form of it (or the source form for that matter) is not included in .py(co) files created by you.  So you are at least as safe importing L/GPLed modules as the nvidia device drivers for linux are being dynamically linked against the kernel.  Just keep in mind that you are not supposed to bundle free software with non-free software, so if you provide your library with a L/GPLed one in the same tarball/zip file or CD, you might run into problems.  This applies too if you are subclassing a class out of a module, since you are not including the other module directly.  (The user can swap the L/GPLed module for a functionally equivalent one and your code won't notice or care).  The only grey area is if you modify the contents of the module at run time, and then distribute the modified module, at which point you would need to distribute the source that produced the modified module.  (Keep in mind that a .pyc, even if it includes a submodule.a=5 line or similar in it, hasn't changed submodule, you'd need to pickle or otherwise save the execution state of the submodule and then distributed the saved state for it to count as changing the sub module).
This I think is the only sane way to look at it, or else an OpenOffice spreadsheet program combined with OO macros would need to be LGPL compatible because OpenOffice itself is LGPL.  Python modules importing a module are *using* that module, not creating a derived work from it.

Comment: I will assume no offense is meant, and the question is asked in good faith. Yes, I've read the LGPL. No, zipfiles are not mentioned. Derivative works, and statically linked libraries are. Statically linked libraries are covered because they include a verbatim copy of the source library in the output. A zipfile is a single file, which includes a derived (compressed) copy of a source library. The terms of the LGPL require the source code for this derived work to be released under the same license. Fair use, or similar legal doctrines may apply, but Python can even directly import the zipfile.